# Pivot Table filtering depending on the combobox value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am trying to have the value of the combobox be the dependant for the filtering of the pivot table. The code below works fine if the combobox value matches the filter sections for the pivot table but that will not be the case so it causes an error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.AddItem "3(Facility Approved),4(Bid Appn Approved),12(Cancelled With Outs)"
ComboBox1.AddItem "3"
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Macro5
Dim sht As Worksheet, pflds As PivotFields, showItems As Boolean
Dim arr

With Worksheets("CT")
    .Range("G1").Value = TextBox2.Value
    .Range("C1").Value = TextBox1.Value
End With
arr = Split(ComboBox1, ",") 'make an array from the combobox value
'show only the values in arr for specific pivot fields
ShowOnlyThese Sheets("BP").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Facility_Status_Id"), arr
ShowOnlyThese Sheets("BC").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Facility_Status_Id"), arr

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Unload Me
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


End Sub
```

This is the code I have tried to amend that problem but I get an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'list to be chosen in the combobox
ComboBox1.AddItem "3(Facility Approved),4(Bid Appn Approved),12(Cancelled With Outs)"
ComboBox1.AddItem "3"
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Macro5
    Dim sht As Worksheet, pflds As PivotFields, showItems As Boolean
    Dim arr

    With Worksheets("Connection Totals")
        .Range("G1").Value = TextBox2.Value
        .Range("C1").Value = TextBox1.Value
    End With
    If ComboBox1.Value = "3(Facility Approved),4(Bid Appn Approved),12(Cancelled With Outs)" Then
    arr = Array("3", "4", "12") 'make an array from the combobox value
    Else
    arr = Array("3")
    'show only the values in arr for specific pivot fields
    ShowOnlyThese Sheets("By Participants").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Facility_Status_Id"), arr
    ShowOnlyThese Sheets("By Corporates").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Facility_Status_Id"), arr
  End If
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Unload Me
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


End Sub

'loop over all items in a pivotfield shows only those matching a value
Sub ShowOnlyThese(pf As PivotField, arrItems)
    Dim pi As PivotItem, haveOne As Boolean
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        On Error Resume Next
        pi.Visible = Not IsError(Application.Match(pi.Value, arrItems, 0))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next pi
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the Error ?

Comment: No error actually but it does not filter the pivot tables to 3,4 and 12 it leaves it at whatever it was previous @Mikku

Comment: What type of data do you want to pass to the array argument `arr` in the procedure `ShowOnlyThese`? - @Tmacjoshua … *BTW* you can't split numbers like you tried via `arr = Split(3, 4, 12, ",")`, you have to split a string (e.g. the current combobox value) to receive tokenized array items (strings again!) - c.f. [MS Help Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function). If you wanted to pass a precise number array as Argument you could simply use the `Array()` function, e.g.  via `arr = Array(3,4,12)` ... is this helpful?

Comment: It is helpful but I am still having trouble. I adjusted the code to are =array(3,4,12) and then else arr = “3” but I can’t seem to get it correct. The array is the pivot table filter. If the user chooses 3...4...12 in the combobox of the userform, I’d like it to filter for just 3,4,12. This works fine if the combobox list is only numbers since the filter consists of only numbers. Since the user would like the logic for the numbers presented in the combobox, I am not able to refer to only the combobox for filtering. @T.M.

Comment: What is in `ShowOnlyThese`?

Comment: @TimWilliams It is because I want the array to filter only the pivot table1 fields Facility_Status_Id for the pivot tables. Before I added logic to the combobox list it was just numbers which allowed me to reference the combobox to filter that specific field in the pivot tables. Now with the logic I need to be specific

Comment: I can guess that, but you're telling us you're calling that sub and nothing is happening, without showing us the code in the sub.  How can we guess what the problem is?

Comment: Will add in the code sorry @TimWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Immediate pane:

```
? application.match("1", array(1,2,3), 0)     '>> error 2042

? application.match("1",array("1","2","3"),0) '>> 1
```

You pivot field values are strings, but the array you're matching against is numeric.
If you pass an array of strings it should work OK.

Your `ShowOnlyThese` has a bug which might leave a field value visible when it should have been hidden, if hiding that value would have meant no values were shown (you must have at least one shown)

```
If ComboBox.Value = "3(Facility Approved),4(Bid Appn Approved),12(Cancelled With Outs)" Then
    arr = Array("3", "4", "12")
Else
    arr = Array("3")
End If

ShowOnlyThese Sheets("By Participants").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
              "Facility_Status_Id"), arr
ShowOnlyThese Sheets("By Corporates").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
               "Facility_Status_Id"), arr
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, where would I actually place that code? Also sometimes the information in the pivot table will not have one of the values that the code would be requesting to filter. Will that bug cause problems if that happens?

Comment: You just need to pass (eg) `Array("3")` instead of `Array(3)`.  you can't hide all of the values in a field, so you will need to decide what you want to do in that case.

Comment: I would never need to hide all the values in the field so that is fine. Where should I place the code you put in the answerÉ

Comment: The code I posted is just to show the problem - as noted in my comment above all you need to do is pass arrays of string values instead of arrays of numbers.

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed the array code. It passed through with no errors but I can not get it to actually filter the pivot tables.

Comment: I added the code I have now after your help in the question as the code tried. Let me know if you see anything that should be amended since it does not filter the pivot table

Comment: Your `End If` is in the wrong place - you only fire the hide/show on the "Else" branch.

Comment: Where should I place it? I tried in all the available rows after arr = Array("3")

Comment: See my edit.  If that's not working then you need to do some debugging inside of `ShowOnlyThese`

Comment: works great thanks, it seemed to slow the code down quite a bit adding in the logic.